# what is collection elements lifecycle in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

The hibernate documentation mentions about the collection elements lifecycle, can you please help me in understanding what is the lifecycle of the elements and how it is maintained in hibernate?

This is the link:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-elements

> An object in a collection might be handled with "value" semantics (its
>   life cycle fully depends on the collection owner), or it might be a
>   reference to another entity with its own life cycle. In the latter
>   case, only the "link" between the two objects is considered to be a
>   state held by the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this link has enough clear explanation

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html

`what is the lifecycle of the elements` ?

**Case 1:**

Take example with two entities `Customer` and `Order`. 1 customer can have many orders. In this case `Customer` acts like Owner for orders elements.

In JPA world `Customer` entity class maintains collection of orders elements like

```
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", orphanRemoval = true)
        private Collection<Order> orders;
```

In above code you see `Customer` class maintains a collection object with collection of orders. In this Customer acts owner for orders. Why ? because of `orphanRemoval = true`, so collections `life cycle` maintained by `Customer`.

When an `Customer` entity object is removed, it gets remove the all orders associated with customer instance.

To keep it simple, this type of relation is called `Composition` in "UML" world. i.e. children can't exist without parent i.e. child `lifecycle` is maintained by parent.

**Case 2**

In this collection might be a reference to another entity with its own life cycle. Please take a look at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html